# Pivot table and get aggregation on multiple arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, ssas

this is my base table:

```
Region year carsSold bicyclesSold
RegX   1999       50          100
RegX   2000      150           30
RegY   1998       60           40
```

What I would like to have as a result is:

```
Region Year          1998 1999 2000
RegX   carsSold         0   50  150
       bicyclesSold     0  100   30  
RegY   carsSold        60    0    0
       bicyclesSold    40    0    0
```

Is there any way to do it in sql server ? Is there a way to do this in excel ? What is the best solution for such data presentation. Could You suggest any software  appropriate for that ?

I know about Pivoting tables in sql server but cant write anything what would give result close to what excactly I want

Comment: You need to format your sample data.  It's impossible for me to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select P.Region,
       P.Item,
       isnull(P.[1998], 0) as [1998],
       isnull(P.[1999], 0) as [1999],
       isnull(P.[2000], 0) as [2000]
from YourTable
unpivot (ItemsSold for Item in (carsSold, bicyclesSold)) as U
pivot (sum(ItemsSold) for year in ([1998], [1999], [2000])) as P
order by P.Region, P.Item
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f178/3/0)

Comment: ok and if there is alo column subregion but I want to have sumed up to region result as shown what to do ?

Comment: @gruber not sure what you mean. You should ask that as  a new question since this is closed fore some reason.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, ANSI-92 compliant code only.  Heck you can even run this in SQLite, except the part about square-bracketing the column name.

I took you **literally** when you say `exactly what I want`

```
select
  case when veh.iscar=1 then t.region else '' end Region,
  veh.type [Year],
  max(case when t.year = 1998
      then carsSold*iscar + bicyclesSold*(1-iscar) else 0 end) [1998],
  max(case when t.year = 1999
      then carsSold*iscar + bicyclesSold*(1-iscar) else 0 end) [1999],
  max(case when t.year = 2000
      then carsSold*iscar + bicyclesSold*(1-iscar) else 0 end) [2000]
from YourTable t
cross join (
  select 'carsSold',1 union all
  select 'bicyclesSold',0) veh(type,iscar)
group by t.region, veh.type, veh.iscar
order by t.region, type desc;

>>
Region  Year         1998   1999    2000
RegX    carsSold        0   50      150
        bicyclesSold    0   100     30
RegY    carsSold        60  0       0
        bicyclesSold    40  0       0
```